# iOS IAP get newest receipt only?

Tags: ios, validation, in-app-purchase, receipt

Is there a way to parse only the latest/newest receipt for receipt validation (In App Purchase)? Parsing them all doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Are you referring to In App Purchase?

Comment: yes, maybe should have written that